# bzip2-ruby Windows Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bzip2

I'm attempted to install the bzip2-ruby gem on Windows 7 x64. Now I don't know if this gem even works on 64-bit Windows. I did install bzip2 which got installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32.

When I go to install, the run the following command:

```
gem install bzip2-ruby -- --with-bz2-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\"
```

When that runs I get the following output:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-bz2-dir
        --with-bz2-include
        --without-bz2-include=${bz2-dir}/include
        --with-bz2-lib
        --without-bz2-lib=${bz2-dir}/lib
        --with-bz2lib
        --without-bz2lib
ERROR:  Error installing bzip2-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-bz2-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32"
checking for bzlib.h... no
checking for BZ2_bzWriteOpen() in -lbz2... no
libbz2 not found, maybe try manually specifying --with-bz2-dir to find it?

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bzip2-ruby-0.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bzip2-ruby-0.2.7/ext/gem_make.out
```

I can verify that the libbz2.a, libbz2.def, and the libbz2.dll.a files exist in the lib folder at the path above.

Am I just missing an extra option when running the command to specify the lib folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GCC (the compiler bundled in RubyInstaller DevKit) to properly work, you need to use path **without** spaces.

The option to `extconf` that you provided has a path with spaces. Please relocate the `lib`, `include` and `bin` folders from bzip2 into a directory without spaces and try again.

Also, you need to have both headers (found in `include` directory) and the import library (found in `lib` directory) for extension compilation to work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're a life saver! It looks like that's exactly what it was, the spaces in the path. The gem successfully installed when I moved the files elsewhere. Thanks again!